# Excel: Copying web table or saner way of merging cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an issue where copying information from a table in a web page to Excel doesn't copy the headers cleanly.  The headers look something like this:

```
#   Line    Part    Part        Description List
    Type    Number  Category                Price
1   Service blah    Core        blah svc    $100
2   Product abc     Subscript   abc stuff   $300
```

When I copy this into Excel, the headers are a mess.  Headers like `Line Type` end up occupying two rows, but `Description` occupies only one.

Is there a better way to copy this into Excel or somehow sanely merge the subsequent rows without losing data?

To note: I've tried merging the cells, but Excel only wants to keep the data from the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the Power Query Add-In.  You can start a Query by scraping a web page, then you have a lot of easy transformation commands available.  For really complex requirements there is a scripting language "M" under the covers.

Comment: Alas, it looks like it requires at least Excel 2010, and we're only set up with 2007 at this time.

Comment: Yes Power Query needs Excel 2010 +. There is a lot of other data and analysis improvements in Excel 2013 - it should be an easy decision to upgrade after 7+ years.

Comment: I wish I were the decision maker for it.

Comment: Excel 2007 should be depreciated to $0 after 7 years. So the business question is: "If we spend around USD100 on Excel 2013, will that save us USD100 of time, and/or help us make a decision that improves our business outcomes by USD100, over the next 7 years?" If you do have an organisation or manager that answers "no" to that proposition, that would tell you a lot about their managerial skills and whether you are productively spending your time working for them :)